# How to use multiprocessing.process() in AWS Lambda to replace .pool()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, multiprocessing

So, after doing some homework on this problem it seems that multiprocessing.pool() won't work in an AWS Lambda, but multiprocessing.process() should work. The problem is that when I try to swap out the code that I know works with the new .process() code, I get a list of  instead of the values I'm looking for. Here's what I'm trying to do:

(note: the commented code is the .pool() example that works, whereas the .process() right below it is what breaks)

```
def evaluate_plans_parallel(foo, baz, bar):
score = {}
input_tuple = []
for k, v in plans.items():
    input_tuple.append({'somevar1': k, 'somevar3': v, 'somevar': foo,'somevar2': baz})

# score_list = []

# pool = multiprocessing.Pool(get_parallel_count())
# pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
# score_list = pool.map(evaluate_single_plan, input_tuple)

processes = []

score_list = []
for tup in input_tuple:
    process = Process(target=evaluate_single_plan, args=(tup,))
    processes.append(process)


for process in processes:
    process.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()

print(processes)

for x in processes:
    for k, v in x.items():
        score[k] = v

top_score = sorted(score.values())[0]
print('Top score: {}: '.format(round(top_score, 3)))
return score
```

Am I doing something obviously incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I needed to sync up the results using .pipe():

```
processes = []
parent_connections = []

for tup in input_tuple:
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    parent_connections.append(parent_conn)

    process = Process(target=evaluate_single_plan, args=(tup, child_conn,))
    processes.append(process)


for process in processes:
    process.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()

for x in parent_connections:
    print(x.recv()])
```

and in the evaluate_single_plan function, instead of returning a value I just needed to send to the child_conn argument that was passed in:

```
child_conn.send(result)
child_conn.close()
```